# LIKE para timestampz sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, query, sequelize-js, operador-like

Eu estou tentando filtras as atividades pela data mas o campo é timestampz. O banco que eu estou  utilizando é o postgres

```
{
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "parent": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 220,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42883",
    "hint": "No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",
    "position": "82",
    "file": "parse_oper.c",
    "line": "731",
    "routine": "op_error",
    "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"operation\" FROM \"activities\" AS \"Activity\" WHERE \"Activity\".\"date\" LIKE '2020-02-25%';"
  },
```

Código:

```
async index(req, res) {
    await Activity.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'operation'],
      where: {
        date: {
          [Op.startsWith]: req.body.date,
        },
      },
    })
      .then(activities => {
        return res.json(activities);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res.status(400).json(err);
      });
  }
```

Com essa query eu consigo filtrar mas no sequelize nao:

```
SELECT * from activities WHERE date::text LIKE '2020-02-25%'
```

Comment: O operador `LIKE` no SQL é um operador entre strings e não outro tipo de dado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi com o `between` utilizando uma lib para manipulação de datas chamada `date-fns`.

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
import { startOfDay, endOfDay, parseISO } from 'date-fns';

import Activity from '../models/Activity';

class Controller {
  async index(req, res) {
    await Activity.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'operation'],
      where: {
        date: {
          [Op.between]: [
            startOfDay(parseISO(req.body.date)),
            endOfDay(parseISO(req.body.date)),
          ],
        },
      },
    })
      .then(activities => {
        return res.json(activities);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res.status(400).json(err);
      });
  }
}
```